# How to make a loop that sums up all previously printed integers?

Tags: loops, sum

I've recently started learning C#, and am new to programming. How do I make a loop that prints out an integer (1), then continues to print out the sum of all previously printed integers, until total number of integers is 20?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
//initialise sum 
int sum = 0;
//i will be the counter from 1 to 21-1
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    //add i to sum
    sum = sum + i;
    //print sum
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

This should do the trick